# Reusable cell not creating from prototype cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an iOS application that loads data from a Firebase Database and then creates a UI Table View with the information. I have created a prototype cell with the reuse identifier "cell" and also a custom cell class with labels. However, when the app loads, the cells created do not have the style I created for the prototype cell even though the reusable cell has the same identifier as the prototype cell. I cannot change the label text of the prototype cell, and all I am getting when I load the app is blank rows with the default cell height, not the customizations I added to the prototype cell.

Here is the code for the UITableView file

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    var ref: DatabaseReference!
        var postList = [Post]()
        var refHandle : UInt!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            //let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts") //.child(userID)
            tableView.register(PostTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
            fetchPosts()

        }


        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return postList.count
        }

        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
            //set cell content
            let contentOfCellPost = postList[indexPath.row]
            cell.title?.text = contentOfCellPost.post_words
            return cell
        }

        func fetchPosts () {

            let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryLimited(toFirst: 10)
            query.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
                for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    if let value = child.value as? NSDictionary {
                        let post = Post()
                        let poster = value["poster"] as? String ?? "Name not found"
                        let post_content = value["post"] as? String ?? "Content not found"
                        post.post_words = post_content
                        post.poster = poster
                        self.postList.append(post)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

}
```

and here is the class I created for the custom cell :

```
import UIKit

class PostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

However, when I change the reusable cell property to

```
cell.textLabel?.text = contentOfCellPost.post_words
```

I can see the text in the table view, however it is still not based off my prototype cell specifications in storyboard.

[image of table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztnat.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
tableView.register(PostTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

If you register a class for a table view then when you dequeue it you get a blank cell of that class not one from a storyboard.  So nothing (IBOutlet, IBAction, etc) will be setup.

If you just want to dequeue the prototype cell defined in a storyboard (or XIB file) then you don't need to register it as well.

Comment: When I delete that line, I can see the background color I set in the storyboard in the app. However, I still cannot see the text label that I connected, even though I set 'cell.label.text = contentOfCellPost.post_words' . Also, it is still not creating a post for each instance in the database, rather it is now UIcells with the default height, not the one I set in the storyboard. @UpholderOfTruth

Comment: Can you post the details of how you have setup the storyboard and I will take another look.  Also remember you don't set the height on the cell but on the UITableView itself.

Comment: I added an image to the question. After I delete the register line of code, I can see the purple in the background but I still cannot see the text even though there is a UIOutlet to the cell class and my code accesses it by setting the cell.label.text to what the post content is.

Comment: 1) What has the purple background?  Is it the cell itself of the content view or something else?  2) How have you set the height of the cells?  3) There appear to be two purple cells in the example.  Is this the correct number of cells you were expecting?  4) Is the IBOutlet linked correctly in the storyboard?

Comment: If you want to you can upload the project or a test version and I can take a closer look.

Comment: The cell content view has the purple background, the height of the cell is set in the table view size inspector, in the example there is about 10 cells that all have the purple background. None have the correct height. The IBOutlet is the label which is connected to the postCell class. I'll upload the project too so you can get a better look @UpholderofTruth

Comment: That upload didn't include the project/workspace files so I can't open it unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry about that! just added it, really appreciate your time @UpholderOfTruth

Comment: What details do I need to be able to login?

Comment: Ok I have skipped the login and manually created a list of posts so I can test it.  First comment is that you have not set the row height of the UITableView so it's defaulted to automatic and there are no constraints on the UILabel to allow the cell to determine it's height.  You need to either one of those to specify the height of the cells.

Comment: Makes sense, also, why is the UILabel not displaying text from the dequeue reusable cell? is that because of the height?

Comment: It works now! All I had to do was change the label so that it was constrained by the cell. Really appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: The problem with the UILabel is that you don't specify anything to fix it's position and size so it's just adopting some kind of default (might be 42 x 46 I think) which isn't big enough.  What I did to test it is put constraints to pin it to the edges of the content view (an centre aligned the text) and it is now visible.

Comment: Just posted my comment as yours came up.  Glad it works.  Looks good and happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You miss to implement **heightForRowAt** OR use dynamic tableView cell height if you wish

Comment: I don't think you understand the problem completely. The table view cell created from the dequeue reusable cell are not following the storyboard specifications of having an image, etc. even though the dequeue reusable cell function has the same identifier as the prototype cell in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Storyboard,remove below line from viewDidLoad function.

```
            tableView.register(PostTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```